# Logging to different places based on various functions

Tags: python, logging

As a test, I wrote the following python code:

```
import logging

def hello():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='hello.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('Hello 1')


def goodbye():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='goodbye.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('Goodbye 1')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='main.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('Main 1')
    hello()
    goodbye()
    logging.info('Main 2')
```

However, instead of logging to the three different files (hello, goodbye, and main), it logged all four statements to the `main.log` file. Why is this so? What would be the correct way to route each of the logs to a different file base on its function.

Comment: I have found the graphic in [the HOWTO section of the `logging` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) to be extremely helpful when trying to see how to set up this flow properly.

Comment: Why you have this behavior: `basicConfig()` gets set the first time it gets called and then does nothing on the subsequent calls. As the docs state: "This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured". The good way to do what you want: Create a new logger with a file handler for each log file you want. Log to those respective loggers; don't log to the root logger. Alternative: set a logging filter on each handler to only log the info it should. Log the root logger, and register the handlers on the root logger.

Comment: @alkasm that's a good idea. Would you want to show that in an answer and I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the code to give you an idea how this can work but I heavily recommend checking out the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial) on loggers, which is excellent.

```
import logging

# this configures the root logger
logging.basicConfig(filename='main.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

def make_logger(name, filename, level):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.propagate = False # so they don't send to root logger
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    logger.setLevel(level)

def hello():
    logger = logging.getLogger('hello')
    logger.info('Hello 1')

def goodbye():
    logger = logging.getLogger('goodbye')
    logger.info('Goodbye 1')

make_logger('hello', 'hello.log', logging.DEBUG)
make_logger('goodbye', 'goodbye.log', logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('Main 1')
hello()
goodbye()
logging.info('Main 2')
```